# CakePHP 3 bake model with same table name from different datasource

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-bake

I'm using `CakePHP 3`.

I have different sources to use and each having a different `users` table.

In short, I'm creating a master panel to manage users from all other applications.

When I bake `users` table from a different connection

```
bin/cake bake model users -c my_con
```

It asks to override earlier baked `users` model.

**How can I bake table with the same name from the different source? maybe under a different namespace.**

And it is impossible to get which index is representing which column.

**How can I map the data with the column name of the table?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a different model name, and explicitly pass the database name via the `--table` option, something like:

```
bin/cake bake model UsersAlias --table users -c my_con
```

Using a different namespace isn't possible directly, for models/tables Bake only supports creating files into plugins, that would be a different namespace, but you'd of course need a separate plugin for each source, which might be a little over the top.

And [**`fetchAll()`**](https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/class-Cake.Database.StatementInterface.html#_fetchAll) has one argument that accepts the fetch type as a string, `'assoc'`, `'obj'`, or `'num'` (default), also available as constants on [**`\Cake\Database\Statement\PDOStatement`**](https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/class-Cake.Database.Statement.PDOStatement.html):

```
$result = $query->fetchAll(\Cake\Database\Statement\PDOStatement::FETCH_TYPE_ASSOC);
```